# How to anchor QDockWidget to top right area?

Tags: qt, qdockwidget

There is a QMainWindow and two QDockWidgets. 
The first widget is docked to the top, the second - to the left.
The result is that the first widget occupies full width and the second widget occupies the remaining area. I want to make it so that the second widget occupies the full height and the first - the remaining area.

To show this visually. "-" - the first widget, "|" - the second, o - central widget.

Default Qt behavior:

```
------
|ooooo
|ooooo
|ooooo
```

I need this:

```
|-----
|ooooo
|ooooo
|ooooo
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please take a look at the `QMainWindow::​setCorner()` [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#setCorner).
This will allow you to customize corner -> dockwidget_area.

For example, according to your question, you should call:

```
QMainWindow * w = ...;
w->setCorner(Qt::TopLeftCorner, Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea);
```

to associate the top left corner with the left dockwidget area.

simple!